# Does suddenly stopping eating meat cause any difficulties to the body?

Tags: health, transitioning-diets

Does a suddenly stopping eating meat after eating it habitually for a long time cause any problems in the human body, particularly to the digestive system?

Answer (score 4):

### Switching to a vegetarian diet can have numerous side effects, but they can be countered.

Two of the most common issues are [increased flatulence and bloating](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/switching-vegan-make-gassy-3596.html).

This is primarily due to a large uptick in fiber consumption, and will eventually level out, or can be avoided by selecting less fibrous foods.

[Anemia, protein deficiency, osteoporosis and vitamin B12 deficiency](http://www.livestrong.com/article/533355-side-effects-of-switching-to-a-vegetarian-diet/) can also occur. These are serious issues which can be addressed through careful dietary changes.

In the end, the switch can be jarring for your body, but a bit of work can make the switch less painful.